# Are there any Natural Language Processing (NLP) libraries in C?

Tags: open-source, c, nlp

Are there any NLP libraries/toolkits similar to NLTK or OpenNLP but in C? Note that I want something in pure C and not in C++.

Comment: I'm not aware of any. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_natural_language_processing gives some pointers but none in C.

Comment: It might be hard to find NLP libraries in pure C. Most of them are Python. There must be a reason. Why do you find that library in C?

Comment: @meisyal I am looking for nlp libraries in C so that I can reach a very tiny executable size without support of remote server, which for some reason I need. I think the reason nlp libraries are usually written in Python, Java etc. is that they are usually written by linguists instead of professional programmers that wrote/